# evaluating a simple complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Why is $\int_{0}^{2\pi}i dt = 2\pi i$? I'd like to use the fundamental theorem of calculus, but the version I know only works for functions $:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Is it that we're just viewing it in the complex plane, so that we're really integrating the constant function $:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ equal to one everywhere, but then renaming everything?

Comment: The fundamental theorem of calculus does extend to contour integrals if the function is holomorphic. The constant function $f(z) = i$ is holomorphic so it applies in this instance.

Comment: the integral of a complex function over a real domain is just the real integral of the real and imaginary parts respectively.

Comment: Thanks Seth. Can you provide me with a reference to this definition? I'd also like to know why this definition extends our notion of what integrals are, maybe in terms of measure theory, or just areas.

Comment: @VienNguyen The book I used for complex analysis is Conway, I'm sure it is in there.  It's probably in any complex analysis book, possibly in the appendix if it has one.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to note that complex integrals are $\mathbb{C}$-linear, so $$\int_0^{2\pi} idt = i\int_0^{2\pi}dt. $$

And you end up with a real integral which you can solve however you want.